# Memory leak while setting root controller again UIViewController with [Navigation Controller, TabBarViewcontroller]

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to understand why my controller instances are not cleared

I have the HomeTabBarViewControlle embedded in the tab bar and navigation controller. On app launch, I am doing this

```
let rootVC = AppStoryboards.Main.instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarViewController")
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
```

Once HomeTabBarViewController with the first controller (i.e HomeDashBoardViewController) loads I have an action in HomeDashBoardViewController which navigating to StatusViewController controller

```
func btnNextAction() {
   let vc = StatusViewController(nibName: "StatusViewController", bundle: nil)
   self.navigationcontroller?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
   self.navigationcontroller?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Due to some logic I have to load the HomeDashBoardViewController again therefore in StatusViewController back button, I am doing this:

```
  //If I do this self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) its ok.

  let vc = ppStoryboards.Main.instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarViewController")
  vc?.selectedIndex = 0
  self.navigationcontroller?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

But the above code is creating multiple instances in the memory for 1st Controller (i.e HomeDashBoardViewController) of the HomeTabBarViewController. The old instances of HomeDashBoardViewController and HomeTabBarViewController not getting cleared

I also tried setting the window root controller again but the same issue. You can check the controller in-memory graph

[image: Multiple instances of controller]

Comment: let vc = ppStoryboards.Main.instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarViewController") - here you create new vc instead of using existed, try self.navigationConreoller.popToRootViewController() if you want to clear the stack

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik But this will go to root view controller

Comment: I mean you don't need to instantiate new vc you can get it from navigationController.viewControllers and pop to it

Comment: I got it but I have multiple root view controller and sometimes its navigating to wrong root controller

Comment: you must instantiate rootViewController only once, and use only it's address in memory to prevent multiple

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I got it. but in my case, vc1 is root controller then from vc1, vc2 is set to root controller, and that's causing the issue. As you said I feel there should be one root controller in the whole app life, am I correct?

Comment: if deinit func is not being called in your vcs stack, check strong links and blocks